# What does DataContext.GetTable<TEntry> do?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Consider I have a DataContext `db`, and there is an Entity class `User`. So when `System.Data.Linq.Table<User> table = db.GetTable<User>();` is called for the first time, does it pull the data from the database immediately, does it use deferred execution, or were the data already loaded from database when `db` was initialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until you enumerate the collection no data is loaded